# convert javascript array to smarty array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, smarty

I have a problem I can not convert javascript array to smarty array.

detail:

```
//javascript array
var tdistance=[];
```

Contains the distance between two points (google map api)
and I have another table smarty {$list_nurseries} that contains all the other information.
I want to combine these two tables to display in  html table with a loop:

```
{section name=i loop=$list_nurseries max=$list_nurseries[0].total}
```

for the moment, I display the table smarty in html table but lacks column distance the is data column in a table javascript tdistance.

Comment: which table I need to change?. tanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the table after it's created to add the data from the javascript array. Smarty is creating the template on the server side, the javascript is executed by the browser on the client side and can't effect the server side template.

Another solution would be to access the google map api with php on the server side instead of using javascript. Then that data could be accessed in your loop.

Comment: The table you create in in your template, with smarty, needs to be modified on the client side with javascript. From what you submited I have no idea what the table is called, but you only have one.

Comment: I have two table: table javascript, smarty table.
I need to convert the javascript table in smarty table displays it in the templat. if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can try 2 things:

Instead of drawing the "smarty table" (as you call it), output the information as json, so javascript can decode it into an array, merge with the data at tdistance and then draw the table.

Another easier option would be: just display the smarty table and add an empty td column with a common identifier (i.e. ). After that, and with jquery or plain javascript, fill every td with the value contained in tdistance for that td id.

Comment: thank you for your solution I have already filled the html table with smarty value but I can not get a replire column empty html value by javascript. how to fill the empty column by the value in the table javascript?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what are you saying. Can you be more clear? What have you tried?

Comment: i want displays javascript array in the html table.   html table display already the data smarty array  with loop                                                                                               {section name=i loop=$list_nurseries max=$list_nurseries[0].total} missing the last column in the html table whose data is in javascript array.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
for (i + + var i = 0; i <nb)
{
  window.document.getElementById (i).innerHTML = km;
}
```

i is the id of the  column displays